# How can i Type an attribute passing by Styled-component Element? here is my case. My problem is on locate props at Cursor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

> error message = Nenhuma sobrecarga corresponde a esta chamada
> Im trying to pass the mouse point locate
> A sobrecarga 1 de 2, '(props: { children?: ReactNode; ref?:
> ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) |
> RefObject | null | undefined; ... 253 more ...;
> onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; } &
> { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gerou o seguinte erro.

```
export default function App() {


const { theme } = useContext(UserThemeContext);

  const [locate, setLocate] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})

  const handleMoveMouse = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLocate({x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY})
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={ theme ?  dark : light }>
      
        <div onMouseMove={(e) => handleMoveMouse(e)}>
        <Cursor locate={locate}/>

          <Home/>

          <GlobalStyle/>

        </div>
      
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}


interface Props {
  locate: {
    x:number,
    y:number
  }
}

export const Cursor = styled.div.attrs<Props>(props => ({
  style: {
    left: (props.locate.x - 20) + 'px',
    top: (props.locate.y - 20) + 'px',
  },
}))`
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #70aca812;
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px #bdf6ff;
`;
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would show the declaration of `Cursor`

Comment: interface Props {
  locate: {
    x:number,
    y:number
  }
}

export const Cursor = styled.div.attrs<Props>(props => ({
  style: {
    left: (props.locate.x - 20) + 'px',
    top: (props.locate.y - 20) + 'px',
  },
}))`
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #70aca812;
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px #bdf6ff;
`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm very happy. i found a way to fix my problem. I don't know if is
> the best way, but it's working.
>
> I Type like StyledComponent<"div", any, Props, never> =
> styled.div.attrs

```
interface Props {
  locate: {
    x:number,
    y:number
  }
}

export const Cursor: StyledComponent<"div", any, Props, never> = styled.div.attrs<Props>(props => ({
  style: {
    left: (props.locate.x - 20) + 'px',
    top: (props.locate.y - 20) + 'px',
  },
}))`
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #70aca812;
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px #bdf6ff;
`;
```